# Where should IDBConnection be put to reduce repeated code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dapper

Most Dapper tutorials use a private `IDBConnection` object to call methods i.e.

```
private IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(...)
```

When using ASP.NET and MVC 5, where should I put this so I do not have to repeat it in every controller/repository using Dapper?
For instance, is there a way to put this in a startup class and use dependency injection like in ASP.NET Core, or some other technique to access it throughout the application?

Comment: Don't re-use the object, always create a new one or you will run into some weird concurrency issues. So create it all the time or inject it (i.e. DI)

Comment: Best option would be Dependency Injection along with Connection Factory, will take care of runtime initialization of the object and it can be in transaction or thread scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best connection creation mechanism as per my experience is the combination of `DependencyInjection` and `ConnectionFactory`.

***Advantages are Multi fold:***

- Create a connection object at runtime in transaction or thread scope
- At runtime change the data provider and thus database of the system ( using Connection Factory)

***What you shall do (in Code):***

**Declare the `IDBConnection` object in the Data access Layer:**

```
[Inject] // Property Injection
public IDBConnection Connection {get; set;}
```

**Declare the binding using a DI framework like Ninject:**

```
Bind<IDBConnection>().ToMethod(ctx => 
ConnectionFactory.CreateDbConnection("DefaultConnection"));
```

**Create the DBConnection Factory as follows:**

*Connection factory fetches the Connection provider and connection string from the config file as follows:*

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=<Value>;Initial Catalog=<Value>;User Id=<Value>;Password=<Value>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Identifier is `DefaultConnection`, which is using the SqlClient provider, but at run time can be changed to the different client like `Oracle, MySql`

```
 using System;
 using System.Data.Common;

 public static class ConnectionFactory
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create DBConnection type based on provider name and connection string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionIdentifier"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DbConnection CreateDbConnection(string connectionIdentifier)
        {
            // Provider name setting
            var providerNameValue = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionIdentifier].ProviderName;

            // Connection string setting
            var connectionStringValue = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionIdentifier].ConnectionString;

            // Assume failure.
            DbConnection connection;

            // Null connection string cannot be accepted
            if (connectionStringValue == null) return null;

            // Create the DbProviderFactory and DbConnection.
            try
            {
                // Fetch provider factory
                var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerNameValue);

                // Create Connection
                connection = factory.CreateConnection();

                // Assign connection string
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionStringValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connection = null;
            }
            // Return the connection.
            return connection;
        }
}
```

***How to use it:***

*For a single call and dispose*

```
using(Connection)
{
 ...
}
```

**For a Transaction context, use as-is, no `using` required**